# Strip Hebrew formatting characters out of string

Tags: php, hebrew

I have a problem that is kicking my ass for a couple of days now.

I have an array of strings and each string contains a single hebrew word.

These words where ripped from a PDF and appear in the array in the same order as shown in the PDF.

I want to take these words and reconstruct them into a sentence in the order they are in the array and the PDF. Seems very simple.

edit: Here is the code, its actually XML I'm looping through, I think its irrelevant but since I'm showing the code I better have it right :)

```
foreach($text->TOKEN as $word) {
    $sentence = $sentence . ' ' . $word;
}

/*
This sentence will sometimes (not always) not have the same order as the XML.
Hebrew is read right to left but thats not the issue, I just want to make a 
string in the same order as the words.
*/
echo $sentence;
```

Its like the words have a mind of their own and the order gets jumbled up to what does not seem like a logical order to a non Hebrew reader. Commas will move around to different words even. But this is not always the case.

I do not read or speak Hebrew but from what I can gather there are some special characters in the language that might be affecting the order? My question is what do I have to do to strip them out?

I'm using PHP for this.

Comment: If this is still relevant, could you provide a sample of your output? I suspect the output is correct, it's just that whatever you use to see it (the text editor, or whatever)  doesn't handle RTL well.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, here are two suggestions:

1. Print out the array of hebrew words with print_r and see what order they're in.
2. Keep in mind that Hebrew is read right to left and not left to right.

Otherwise, please provide more of your code for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited my question to include code.